# trying to do ward clustering on n by n matrix in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I have a similarity score between 0 and 1 from each entry to every other entry in an 100 by 100 matrix. So e.g. `[0,0]` would be `1`, `[0,1]` might be `.54` etc.  The similarity score was generated using Shannon Jensen divergence.

I want to use ward clustering (but am open to other suggestions) to cluster these together and I tried the following code:

```
    x = np.array(mylist)
    print x.shape#(100,100)
    clustering = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ward(x)
    scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(clustering)

but I am getting the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/ward.py", line 38, in <module>
    clustering = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.ward(y)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 465, in ward
    return linkage(y, method='ward', metric='euclidean')
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 620, in linkage
    y = _convert_to_double(np.asarray(y, order='c'))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py", line 928, in _convert_to_double
    X = X.astype(np.double)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Do I need to do some transformation on my array first or use some other method?

Comment: "I want to use ward clustering (but am open to other suggestions)" (if I got the intended meaning right)? Sure, use whatever you like, who are we to restrict you? ;)

Comment: On a serious note, please include all the relevant parts of the stacktrace (all if you can't tell for sure which are relevant). And what you're trying to do if you wish to hear "suggestions".

Comment: I put the rest of the stack trace in the post.  I tried running the same code with random data: x = np.random.normal(size=(num_samples,100))
and comparing the dimensions of the array i originally provided verses one that does work with random data.

not sure why you have to get rude with Sheesh, RTFM

Comment: figured out the issue, one of the rows in the array got garbled so it looked like the shape was ok but in fact was not.